# How do I rename XML tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML-

```
<CATALOG>
    <NAME>C1</NAME>
    <CD>
        <NAME>Empire Burlesque</NAME>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <NAME>Hide your heart</NAME>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to replace the NAME tag in catalog to CATALOG-NAME and the the NAME tag in CD's to CD-NAME which should make my xml look like this-

```
<CATALOG>
    <CATALOG-NAME>C1</CATALOG-NAME>
    <CD>
        <CD-NAME>Empire Burlesque</CD-NAME>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <CD-NAME>Hide your heart</CD-NAME>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: I have been trying using XSLT and I'm not finding any function which would change the tag vale. The example I posted above is similar to what I need to do with a larger XML file where I would be replacing tags.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the identity transform with overrides for the elements you want to rename:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CD/NAME">
        <CD-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CD-NAME>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CATALOG/NAME">
        <CATALOG-NAME><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></CATALOG-NAME>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please include a 1 line description of how this code works? Thanks!

Comment: The identity transform produces output identical to its input. In this case, we slightly modify the identity transform to match `CD/NAME` and `CATALOG/NAME` elements and produce the renamed output for those particular tag names. Everything else remains the same. This is a common pattern.