# Replace xml tags to html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hello all I wnt to replace some xml node tags to html tags

Example: `<emphasis role="bold">Diff.</emphasis>`

i want to convert it to `<b>Diff.</b>`

Example: `<emphasis role="italic">Diff.</emphasis>`

i want to convert it to `<i>Diff.</i>`

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a job for xslt

Comment: @SanthoshNayak: can you give an (extensive) use-case so we can test the behavior?

Comment: @CommuSoft i have got a xml file, i have to convert it to html.. so i am converting xml node tags to related html tags.

Comment: @SanthoshNayak: sure, but as the *How to ask a question* suggests, you better provide some sample input and output such that people can verify their program/... before answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7246969/67579) suggests, *XSLT* is the de-facto standard to process XML from one format to another.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//emphasis[@role='bold']">
        <b><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></b>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//emphasis[@role='italic']">
        <i><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></i>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*XSLT* makes use of *XPath* queries to query and process the content. For instance `//emphasis[@role='bold']` matches any tag (no matter how deep) that has an attribute `role` with value `'bold'`, within such blocks, you specify how to process it. By presenting it within `<b>...</b>` blocks, XSLT will present the output within these blocks as well. And `select="node()"` inserts the content of the node there.

**Example**: say the above code is stored in `process.xslt`, you can process this using `xsltproc` (or another XSLT processor):

```
xsltproc process.xslt testinput.xml
```

If testinput is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
<emphasis role="italic"><foo>Diff<emphasis role="italic">bar</emphasis></foo>.</emphasis>
<emphasis role="bold">Diff.</emphasis>
</test>
```

the resulting output is:

```
$ xsltproc process.xslt testinput.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<test>
<i><foo>Diff<i>bar</i></foo>.</i>
<b>Diff.</b>
</test>
```

**To output it as HTML**, you can override the `main` of the XSLT by including

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

in the `<xsl:stylesheet>`. In that case, the output is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body><test>
<i><foo>Diff<i>bar</i></foo>.</i>
<b>Diff.</b>
</test></body>
</html>
```