# How to make XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the xml file structure below, but I need to transform it to the structure where "Shipper" and "Supplier" in the node "Type1"

Could you please advice me how to do that with xslt?

```
      <Data>
        <Shipper>11111</Shipper>
        <Supplier>22222</Supplier>
        <Type1>
          <NumberOfConnections>2</NumberOfConnections>
          <Quantity>
            <Amount>2042</Amount>
            <Unit>AAAAA</Unit>
          </Quantity>
          <UserCategory>GGV</UserCategory>
        </Type1>
      </Data>
```

I would like to have the structure like on the file below:

```
      <Data>
        <Type1>
        <Shipper>11111</Shipper>
        <Supplier>22222</Supplier>
          <NumberOfConnections>2</NumberOfConnections>
          <Quantity>
            <Amount>2042</Amount>
            <Unit>AAAAA</Unit>
          </Quantity>
          <UserCategory>GGV</UserCategory>
        </Type1>
       </Data>
```

Thank you!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246666/how-do-i-rename-xml-tags-using-xslt